# PHP: get the first day of september using DateTime-Class

Tags: php, datetime, get

I have a problem using the DateTime-Class. I try to get the first day of september:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/d/m', "2014/30/09");

echo "<br />this day: ".$date->format("Y/d/m");

$date->modify('last day of october');
echo "<br />works: first day of october: ".$date->format("Y/d/m");
// Output: 2014/31/10

$date->modify('first day of september');
echo "<br />dont work: first day of september: ".$date->format("Y/d/m");
// Output: 2014/31/10

$date->modify('first day of august');
$date->modify('+1 month');
echo "<br />works: first day of september: ".$date->format("Y/d/m");
// Output: 2014/01/09
```

can someone help me?

We are running: PHP Version 5.4.36-0+deb7u3 on Debian 3.2.63-2+deb7u2 x86_64

The default timezone is: Europe/Berlin

Comment: If I run just 

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/d/m', "2014/30/09");

$date->modify('first day of september'); echo "
dont work: first day of september: ".$date->format("Y/d/m");

it works just fine without any other modify's...

Comment: What is the output, and what is the problem?

Comment: I have edited the question, maybe problem with my time zone?

Answer (score 0):

If we know that the first day will always represented as `1` why can't we just use:

`$date->modify('September 1');`

It produces the desired output when using previous `modify` calls.

Full code:

```
<?php
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/d/m', "2014/30/09");

echo "<br />this day: ".$date->format("Y/d/m");

$date->modify('last day of october');
echo "<br />works: first day of october: ".$date->format("Y/d/m");

$date->modify('September 1');
echo "<br />dont work: first day of september: ".$date->format("Y/d/m");

$date->modify('first day of august');
$date->modify('+1 month');
echo "<br />works: first day of september: ".$date->format("Y/d/m");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$new_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/d/m', "2014/15/09");
echo "Date To be changed: ".$new_date->format("Y/d/m");
$new_date->modify('first day of september');
echo "<br><br><b>Changed Date : </b><br> First day of september: ".$new_date->format("Y/d/m");
```